# Would a valid German study visa create a travel history?

Tags: visas, germany

I have a valid German study visa but I won't travel to Germany with it. I have cancelled my plan. Does only having a visa in my passport create my travel history? Without traveling to Germany, will I have a travel history record just by having a valid visa in my passport?

the reason I am asking this is:

I have got admission in Germany as well as in US. My US admission letter came late. So I started my German visa process and got the visa. Now I have decided to go to US for studies instead of Germany. I have cancelled my German visa and they have put a stamp "cancelled without prejudice" stamp on my German visa. Will that create any negative impact of my US study visa process? Now since I did not travel to Germany, and I don't want the US embassy to know about my cancelled German visa, I thought I should renew my passport and tell the US embassy that I lost my old one. What do you suggest?

Comment: What do you mean by a "travel history record?" For what purpose? Are you referring to the impact on future visa applications?

Comment: Who, other than you, do you think is maintaining the history?

Comment: In law, the phrase "without prejudice" basically means that any rights, privileges or immunities involved are not affected by the act. Thus, when your document is cancelled without prejudice, it means that there was no negative impact to you attached to the cancellation and others who see the cancelled document should not infer that anything negative occurred.

Comment: Why did you remove the clarifying explanation from the question? That orphaned several of the comment responses, and the addition was very helpful for figuring out what you mean by "travel history". I have rolled back the deletion.

Answer (score 3):

- You have been granted a student visa by Germany. Other visa officials will see that as a good thing, a relatively strict country investigated you and gave you a visa.
- You have changed your plans on a significant issue. Other visa officials *may* see that as a bad thing and consider you unreliable, but they understand that a student's plans can change.

Basically, you had the chance to go to Germany where you *could* have tried to overstay and work illegally, and you didn't do it. Point in your favor, but it doesn't guarantee future visa.